# c++ pass data source function as parameter

Tags: c++, function, c++11, static, non-static

I have a static function:

```
void E::createEP(std::list<double>* ret, double length, double (*getHeight)(double)) {
  // magic
  double sampleIntervall = //from magic

  double dist = 0;
  while (length - dist > -0.1) {
    ret->push_back(dist, (*getHeight)(dist));
    dist += sampleIntervall;
  }
}
```

In different calls I have two different functions to pass as getHeight():

- A function in a database wrapper class which is not static
- A function within the same Object of type `E` as `createEP()` (for "recreating" with different parameters), which needs to access Elements fields and can thus not be static, either.

Is it somehow possible to pass non-static functions as parameters to a static function?

If not, what would be the most elegant alternative? I don't want to duplicate the entire code in `createEP()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can use is a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).  It will wrap a callable type be that a function, member function, object with an overloaded function operator.  You just need to supply the signature to use.  So in you case you would have

```
void E::createEP(std::list<double>* ret, double length, std::function<double(double)> getHeight)
```

Then to bind the member function with the object you want to call it on you can use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) like

```
[&](double val){ return object.FunctionName(val); }
```

or [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) like

```
std::bind(&ClassName::FunctionName, &object)
```

Comment: You can drop the `()` on the lambda.  And I'd put the much-shorter (and possibly more peformant) lambda before the `std::bind` myself.  (`std::bind` actually needs to create a data structure with both pointers, and actually invoke the member function pointer, due to `std::function` exposing access to the underlying type).

Comment: @Yakk Good call on making the lambda first.

Comment: what would I put as the Parameter in the lambda Expression?

Comment: sorry, I seem not to be able to edit my comment:
what would I put:
    [&]{ return this->getElevation(//here?);}

Comment: @Niklas If it is a static value just hard code it. If you want the option to change it then you can use `[&](double val){ return object.function(val); }`.  I updated the answer as I forgot you need to pass a value to it.

Comment: @Niklas No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

With c++11 the probably best option is to use [`std::function<double(double)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of the raw function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::function` is really useful here

see this:

```
#include <functional>

using funType = std::function<void(double)>;
struct foo
{
  void bar(double d) {};
  static void call(funType f) {};
};

void foo2(double)
{
}

//...       
foo f;
//create lambda which calls member function
auto f1 = [&f](double d) { f.bar(4); };

foo::call(f1); //indirect call to member function due to lambda
foo::call(&foo2); //call to non-member function.
//...
```

`std::function` can hold a function pointer or a lambda which makes this really nice compared to c-style function pointers.

You can also call it with member functions directly but that requires `bind`. 
I think the solution with wrapping the call in a lambda looks a bit better for this.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to `std::function`

```
void E::createEP(std::list<double>* ret,
                 double length,
                 const std::function<double (double)>& getHeight)
```

You may use directly template

```
template <typename F>
void E::createEP(std::list<double>* ret,
                 double length,
                 F&& getHeight)
```

with body in both case

```
{
  // magic
  double sampleIntervall = //from magic

    double dist = 0;
    while (length - dist > -0.1) {
        ret->push_back(dist, getHeight(dist));
        dist += sampleIntervall;
    }
}
```